# Passing argument 1 of `copyInfo` from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

Im still new to C programing and having a bit of difficulties with concepts. I'm getting this warnings when I try to compile the program:
1)Warning:passing argument 1 of `copyInfo` from incompatible pointer type
2)Warning:passing argument 2 of `copyInfo` from incompatible pointer type

Why am I getting these warnings? The goal of the program is to copy all of the info from `inputFile` to `outputFile`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int badProgram(const char *const program){
    printf("The program is missing some of the files!");
    return -1;
}

int missingInputTxt(const char *const fileName){
    printf("The file is missing! Please provide the file!");
    return -1;
}

int copyInfo(FILE *input, FILE *ouput){
    char singleLine[150];
    int result = 0;

    while(fgets(singleLine, sizeof(singleLine), input) != NULL){
        fprintf(ouput, "%s\n", singleLine);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int result = 0;

    if(argc < 2){
        return badProgram(argv[0]);
    }
    else{
        FILE *input;
        FILE *output;

        if((input = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
            return missingInputTxt(argv[1]);
        }

        if((output = fopen(argv[2], "w")) != NULL){
            result = copyInfo(argv[1], argv[2]);
            fclose(output);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: argv[1] is a char * not a FILE *, need to fopen a valid file pointer first

Comment: You've got an off-by-one-error in your check for `argc`. You need to check `if (argc < 3)` is you want to access `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyInfo` expects arguments of type `FILE*`. You are calling it with `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, which are of type `char*`. Those are incompatible types.

You need to use:

```
result = copyInfo(input, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = copyInfo(argv[1], argv[2]);
```

`argv[1]` and `argc[2]` are not file pointers . You pass wrong *type* of parameters to this function .

Write like this -

```
result = copyInfo(input,ouput);     // as input and output are file pointers
```

*Also you should close files that you open .*

```
 fclose(input);
 fclose(output);
```